# Using a Class's pygame.rect inside another class

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to use the self.rect.x which is made in player1 inside the class player2. The code is meant to make player 2 chase player 1. Below is a very rough summary of what my current code looks like.

```
class player1 (pygame.sprite.Sprite)

  def __init__ (self,x,y):

  #creates img, rect, x and y



class player 2 (pyagme.sprite.Sprite)

  def __init__ (self,x,y)

  #repeats process

  def chase (self):

    self.rect.x += self.change_x
    self.rect.y += self.change_y

    dx = self.rect.x - player1.rect.x
    dy = self.rect.y - player1.rect.y
    dist = math.hypot(dx,dy)
    dx = dx/dist
    dy = dy/dist

    self.rect.x += dx * self.change_x
    self.rect.y += dx * self.change_y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite close to the solution. What you need is a reference inside player2, to the player1.

```
class player2 (pyagme.sprite.Sprite)

  def __init__ (self, x, y, chased_object)
      self.chased_object = chased_object

  def chase (self):
    # same code as before, but replace all "player1" by "self.chased_object"
```

Instantiate your classes like this :

```
the_player_1 = player1(50, 100)
the_player_2 = player2(200, 50, the_player_1)
```

For code clarity, it may be important to name the reference variable "chased_object" and not "chased_player", to express the fact that the player2 could chase anything that has a "rect" attribute. It may be a player, a monster, a spaceship, a banana, ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I added the changes and it seemed to work but unfortunately I couldn't get the chase code to work. So instead I decided to put 'global player1' in my game loop, thus allowing me to use it in the player2 loop, and then just + and - player2s x and y depending on whether they were greater or less than player1's x and y.

Comment: OK. Maybe you could post in a comment (or in another question) why the chase code didn't work in your first try. We may help. Adding `global player1` surely works, but it is not a best practice in python coding.